# Newbie in Apache Drill: Cannot see Web Console

Tags: apache-drill

I downloaded apache-drill-1.2.0 on a ubuntu 14.04 64 box.
Extracted the tar.zip contents, went to bin folder and ran drill.

Now I tried to open: `http://localhost:8047`, but I'm getting a "can't establish a connection to server" error.

I tried to enable https by http.ssl_enabled: "TRUE". But still cannot open the web console either using http/https.

### Here are some relevant logs:

```
himanshu@himanshu-HP-ProBook-4430s:~/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/bin$ ./drill-embedded 
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/classb/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
15/11/13 15:38:56 INFO config.DrillConfig: Loading base configuration file at jar:file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/drill-common-1.2.0.jar!/drill-default.conf.
15/11/13 15:38:56 INFO config.DrillConfig: Loading 7 module configuration files at: 
    - jar:file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/drill-storage-hbase-1.2.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
    - jar:file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/drill-hive-exec-shaded-1.2.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
    - jar:file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/drill-common-1.2.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
    - jar:file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/drill-jdbc-storage-1.2.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
    - jar:file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/drill-java-exec-1.2.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
    - jar:file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/drill-mongo-storage-1.2.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
    - jar:file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/drill-storage-hive-core-1.2.0.jar!/drill-module.conf.
15/11/13 15:38:56 INFO config.DrillConfig: Loading override config. file at file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/conf/drill-override.conf.
15/11/13 15:38:56 INFO config.DrillConfig: Loading override Properties parameter {user=, password=, zk=local}.
15/11/13 15:39:00 INFO reflections.Reflections: Reflections took 4050 ms to scan 7 urls, producing 5602 keys and 21840 values 
com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.elapsed(Ljava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)J
apache drill 1.2.0 
"got drill?"
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> !quit
15/11/13 15:39:02 INFO config.DrillConfig: Loading base configuration file at jar:file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/drill-common-1.2.0.jar!/drill-default.conf.
15/11/13 15:39:02 INFO config.DrillConfig: Loading 7 module configuration files at: 
    - jar:file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/drill-storage-hbase-1.2.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
    - jar:file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/drill-hive-exec-shaded-1.2.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
    - jar:file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/drill-common-1.2.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
    - jar:file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/drill-jdbc-storage-1.2.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
    - jar:file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/drill-java-exec-1.2.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
    - jar:file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/drill-mongo-storage-1.2.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
    - jar:file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/drill-storage-hive-core-1.2.0.jar!/drill-module.conf.
15/11/13 15:39:02 INFO config.DrillConfig: Loading override config. file at file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/conf/drill-override.conf.
15/11/13 15:39:02 INFO config.DrillConfig: Loading override Properties parameter {user=, password=, zk=local}.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.elapsed(Ljava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)J
    at org.apache.drill.common.util.PathScanner.scanForImplementations(PathScanner.java:110)
    at org.apache.drill.common.util.PathScanner.scanForImplementationsArr(PathScanner.java:86)
    at org.apache.drill.common.logical.data.LogicalOperatorBase.getSubTypes(LogicalOperatorBase.java:92)
    at org.apache.drill.common.config.DrillConfig.<init>(DrillConfig.java:82)
    at org.apache.drill.common.config.DrillConfig.create(DrillConfig.java:226)
    at org.apache.drill.common.config.DrillConfig.create(DrillConfig.java:152)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.<init>(DrillConnectionImpl.java:92)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillJdbc41Factory.newDrillConnection(DrillJdbc41Factory.java:66)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillFactory.newConnection(DrillFactory.java:69)
    at net.hydromatic.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.connect(UnregisteredDriver.java:126)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
    at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:167)
    at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:213)
    at sqlline.Commands.close(Commands.java:925)
    at sqlline.Commands.quit(Commands.java:889)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sqlline.ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(ReflectiveCommandHandler.java:36)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:742)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:621)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:375)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:268)
15/11/13 15:39:02 INFO config.DrillConfig: Loading base configuration file at jar:file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/drill-common-1.2.0.jar!/drill-default.conf.
15/11/13 15:39:02 INFO config.DrillConfig: Loading 7 module configuration files at: 
    - jar:file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/drill-storage-hbase-1.2.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
    - jar:file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/drill-hive-exec-shaded-1.2.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
    - jar:file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/drill-common-1.2.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
    - jar:file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/drill-jdbc-storage-1.2.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
    - jar:file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/drill-java-exec-1.2.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
    - jar:file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/drill-mongo-storage-1.2.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
    - jar:file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/drill-storage-hive-core-1.2.0.jar!/drill-module.conf.
15/11/13 15:39:02 INFO config.DrillConfig: Loading override config. file at file:/home/himanshu/Downloads/softwares/apache-drill-1.2.0/conf/drill-override.conf.
15/11/13 15:39:03 INFO config.DrillConfig: Loading override Properties parameter {user=, password=, zk=local}.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.elapsed(Ljava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)J
    at org.apache.drill.common.util.PathScanner.scanForImplementations(PathScanner.java:110)
    at org.apache.drill.common.util.PathScanner.scanForImplementationsArr(PathScanner.java:86)
    at org.apache.drill.common.logical.data.LogicalOperatorBase.getSubTypes(LogicalOperatorBase.java:92)
    at org.apache.drill.common.config.DrillConfig.<init>(DrillConfig.java:82)
    at org.apache.drill.common.config.DrillConfig.create(DrillConfig.java:226)
    at org.apache.drill.common.config.DrillConfig.create(DrillConfig.java:152)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.<init>(DrillConnectionImpl.java:92)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillJdbc41Factory.newDrillConnection(DrillJdbc41Factory.java:66)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillFactory.newConnection(DrillFactory.java:69)
    at net.hydromatic.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.connect(UnregisteredDriver.java:126)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
    at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:167)
    at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:213)
    at sqlline.Commands.close(Commands.java:925)
    at sqlline.Commands.closeall(Commands.java:899)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:649)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:375)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:268)
```

---

Guava library present in distribution: guava-14.0.1
Please help.

Comment: Are you saying you tried to make a request to localhost on the Ubuntu box or from your local machine? It sounds like you have Drill running on a remote machine. You can either curl `localhost:8047` while SSH'd into the remote machine to see if the web console is up or hit the ip/DNS on your remote box from your local machine `<remote_machine_ip_or_dns>:8042`.

Comment: I am not running drill on any remote system. I have a single standalone ubuntu laptop. Not sure, why something this straight forward is not working for me :(

Comment: Got it. Thanks for adding the logs. In my experience, you need to start Drill with this command: `./sqlline -u jdbc:drill:zk=local` described [here](http://drill.apache.org/docs/starting-stopping-drill/).

Comment: @danielcorin on ubuntu it is started using `drill-emdedded`

Answer (score 2):

You started with `./drill-embedded`

Right. First of all you need to check, Drill is running or not on 8047 port.

Using this command check is there any process started on this port.

```
   netstat -tlnp | grep 8047
```

you can also use `jps` command and check is there any process with name `sqlline`.

If its showing a process running on this port. Then there may be issue with mapping `localhost`. Then you can try

```
http://<IP_ADDRESS>:8047
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. The process is started and shown in jps. But cannot see any entry for port 8047 when running netstat command. Are there any specific logs/commands which may help in understanding this behavior?

Comment: Adding more info. Tried drill 1.1 and 1.3 rc on my laptop. Same errors. Copied the 1.2 tar.gz on a remote ubuntu server, Drill runs fine. Web UI appears instantly. So it is something specific to my machine. Investigating more.....

Comment: Have you compiled source code on your machine?  You got `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.elapsed(Ljava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)` So you can debug at `org.apache.drill.common.util.PathScanner.scanForImplementations(PathScanner.java:110)` to check the exact error.

Answer (score 0):

You should start drill first.. Then try to open localhost:8047